# Use Hibernate Formula annotation for reference loading

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 entities - `Storage`, `Item` and `Relation`. `Storage` has several `Item` entities and items are bound by `Relation` entities. And relations can bind items from different storage. For simplification let say I want to load relation by query and want to do it fast. So now I have 3 query - loading for `Storage`, loading for all Items under storage and load of relation (`List<Relation> relations` field).

Now I want to tell hibernate how to load `Collection<Relation> extRelation` field. I tried `@Formula`, `@CalculatedColumn` and different combination of `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinFormula`. But generated query is wrong (or ignores my query). Also I cannot use `@OneToMany` because of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9897 bug.

Latest Exception is:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table
>   "TEST_STORAGES_TEST_RELATIONS" not found; SQL statement:

```
SELECT extrelatio0_.test_storages_storage_id AS test_sto1_2_0_
 ,extrelatio0_.extRelation_from_item_id AS extRelat2_3_0_
 ,extrelatio0_.extRelation_to_item_id AS extRelat3_3_0_
 ,relation1_.from_item_id AS from_ite1_1_1_
 ,relation1_.to_item_id AS to_item_2_1_1_
 ,relation1_.relation_id AS relation3_1_1_
 ,relation1_.storage_id AS storage_4_1_1_
FROM test_storages_test_relations extrelatio0_
INNER JOIN test_relations relation1_ ON extrelatio0_.extRelation_from_item_id = relation1_.from_item_id
 AND extrelatio0_.extRelation_to_item_id = relation1_.to_item_id
WHERE extrelatio0_.test_storages_storage_id = ?
```

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_storages")
public class Storage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "storage_id")
    private BigInteger storageId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Item.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "storage_id", updatable = false)
    @MapKey
    private List<Item> items;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Relation.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "storage_id", updatable = false)
    @Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Relation> relations;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula =
            @JoinFormula(
                    value = "(select dep.from_item_id, dep.to_item_id from test_relations dep where dep.storage_id = ?)"
            )
        )
    })
    private Collection<Relation> extRelation;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private BigInteger itemId;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "storage_id")
    private BigInteger storageId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_relations")
public class Relation {
    @Column(name = "relation_id")
    private BigInteger relationId;

    @Column(name = "storage_id")
    private BigInteger storageId;

    @EmbeddedId
    private RelationPK pk;
}

@Embeddable
public class RelationPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "from_item_id")
    private BigInteger fromItemId;

    @Column(name = "to_item_id")
    private BigInteger toItemId;
}
```

All sources available on https://github.com/ainlolcat/test_hibernate_formula

Comment: Wait, isn't your query supposed to return the same results as `@OneToMany List<Relation> relations`? Why use custom query then?

Comment: @Roman yes it is. But only for example. In future I want to load only relations which points from one storage to another.